# Adding UITableView on top of UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I want to add UITableView on top of UIView. Here's an image [image: the image] of what exactly i want to do.
Sample code link/tutorial is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) + [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is all what you need. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is the image you've provided from a website? It looks very much like a combo box in a standard HTML file.